# removing duplicates from different Excel files

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am having many excel files in a folder, I have to create a tool to read those files and remove duplicate data between files using PHP and MYSQL.

So that i tried to read the data using Excel reader and store them in database

- I was struggling to remove the duplicate fields
- And also exporting the remaining data to excel file

Comment: Before storing them in the Database, check if entries are already there. If you only insert new records, your duplicates are gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it may help you with your duplications http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/10897_2201621_2/Deleting-Duplicate-Rows-in-a-MySQL-Database.htm 
And if you want to import the data using php Click [Here]http://www.programmingfacts.com/export-mysql-data-into-excelcsv-via-php/